# How I can inject my custom service to ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, resteasy

We have using rest-easy 3.0.11 and want to inject our custom service to in our ContainerRequestFilter.

Here is what we have tried

```
@Provider
public class CustomFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    private CustomService customService;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        customService.do();
    }
}
```

In our code customService is always null, so what is wrong in our code?